# Querying Model in Another App

Tags: django, orm

I have two apps `projects` and `tasks`.  In my `projects` app I would like to have a count of the number of tasks **based on their status** per project.  For example, 11 tasks might be true and 5 tasks might be false.

`tasks models.py`

```
class Task(models.Model):
    status = models.BooleanField()
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project)
```

`projects models.py`

```
class TaskCount(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return super(TaskCount, self).get_query_set().annotate(tasks=Count('task'))
```

That simple manager counts all the tasks but if I try to filter by status it says the attribute cannot be found.  Because its looking for the attribute on the projects table instead of the tasks table.

How can I query by the task's status while still retaining the "count tasks by project" approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you have two competely separate apps here, rather than just two models in the same app. Regardless, the method is the same: you use the double-underscore syntax to filter across relationships.

```
Project.taskcount.filter(task__status=False)
```

Comment: Thank you.  If I could pick your brain just a little longer.  How do I access the two filters I've created (one for true and one for false)?  My view code looks something like `var1 = Project.with_tasks.filter(task__status=False)` and `var2 = Project.with_tasks.filter(task__status=True)`.  How do I access the vars in the template?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You access them like any other variable passed to the template context.

Comment: I tried `{{ var1 }}` and `{{ project.var1 }}`.  I'm accessing the variable in a loop `{% for project in object_list %}`.  I was getting the total count (open and closed) for each project by using `{{ project.tasks }}` which was created in the model manager but I want a more specific count which is why I started the question.  Hope this helps.  Edit:  It might be relevant that I'm using a generic ListView.

Comment: Well now I'm even more confused. Where are these variables defined? How are you passing them to the template? You should probably post your view code (preferably in a new question).

Comment: I've done so here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25043682/passing-a-query-set-to-a-template  Thanks for taking the time out of your day to help.  I really appreciate it.