# Passing a Query Set to a Template

Tags: django, orm

I have a template that lists out all of the projects that have been created.  I've used the `models.Manager` to create a query set that counts the number of `tasks` a particular `project` has.  I've also created two variables in `views.py` that filter the results to provide more specific output.  Within my template I want to be able to display `Project X has 11 tasks open` and `Project Y has 5 tasks open` (in a tabular format).

It should be noted that I can access the `TaskCount` manager's result by using `{{ project.tasks }}` but what I'm really interested in is accessing the `open_set` variable in my template.

`models.py`

```
class TaskCount(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return super(TaskCount, self).get_query_set().annotate(tasks=Count('task'))

class Project(models.Model):
    # Model Fields
    # some fields
    # Model Managers
    with_tasks = TaskCount()
```

`views.py`

```
class ListProject(ListView):
    model = Project
    template_name = 'list_project.html'
    # Queries
    open_set = Project.with_tasks.filter(task__status=0)
    closed_set = Project.with_tasks.filter(task__status=1)
```

`list_project.html`

```
{% for project in object_list %}
    <tr>
        <!-- works -->
        <td><a href="{{ project.get_absolute_url }}">{{ project.name }}</a></td>
        <!-- works -->
        <td>{{ project.created_by }}</td>
        <!-- doesn't work -->
        <td>{{ open_set }}</td>
        <!-- doesn't work -->
        <td>{{ project.closed_set }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't put those queries there at the class level: the ListView doesn't know about them and won't pass them anywhere. Instead you should override `get_context_data` and return them from there.

```
class ListProject(ListView):
    ...
    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(ListProject, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['open_set'] = Project.with_tasks.filter(task__status=0)
        context['closed_set'] = Project.with_tasks.filter(task__status=1)
        return context
```

Comment: Ah, this makes sense.  It works, however, `{{ open_set }}` seems to be showing the projects that have open tasks instead of counting the number of tasks for the particular project.  E.g. the output is `[<Project: Hello>, <Project: Some Project>]` for both projects (desired output would be `2` for the first and `1` for the second).

Comment: You need to iterate through the set and access `tasks` on each one, as that's the name you gave the annotated value.

Comment: Okay so this is weird.  I have two issues, first my results are raised to the power of themself and second my results are all on one line instead of being on their appropriate lines.  So every line has this list 1, 4, 16.  Whereas it should read Item1: 1, Item2: 2, Item3: 4.  I got these results by looping over `open_set` and calling `{{ x.tasks }}`.

Comment: Just wanted to say thanks for all the great advice.  Today I finally applied it properly.  I was querying from the projects manager when I should have been querying from the tasks manager.  Anyway, I did a ton of research with all the great context you gave me and I learned a great deal.  Once again, thank you very very much.